# react-native-firebase v6 - Android - notification is being displayed although it shouldn't

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

React-Native v0.61.2
react-native-firebase v6.3.4
No 3rd party library for displaying notification.

According to documentation v6 does not include notification library (was extracted out to Notifee) - But while testing by sending message via Firebase Console - a notification was displayed while app on background - not what I expected.

How did that happened?

Answer (score 3):

Do read this part of docs, https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#displaying-a-notification

it clearly states that ***The Firebase Cloud Messaging SDKs for Android and iOS allow for notifications to be displayed on devices when the application is either quit or in the background. The Firebase Console, Firebase Admin SDKs and REST API all allow a notification property to be attached to a message.***

***If an incoming message with this property exists, and the app is not currently visible (quit or in the background), a notification is displayed on the device. However, if the application is in the foreground, an event will be delivered containing the notification data and no visible notification will be displayed.***

so it might be firebase SDK (most probably).

Answer (score 1):

From the Invertase doc it is only said that it does not work on iOS but without any problem on Android.

Comment: Thanks, Where does it says so?

Comment: I maybe spoke too fast but all the infos are on this issue: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2566

Comment: Are you sure that you did not add react-native-push-notification ?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the end I found out that there was a native notification mechanism that was implemented a while ago and it was responsible for the notifications I saw... Thanks all for answering.

Comment: I implemented the push notifications using rnfirebase v6. But the problem is i cannot clear the push notifications that are delivered. Is there any way to clear it? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475533/react-native-firebase-unable-to-clear-delivered-notification-on-v6